# How to make user signup once, if I've built a business with two services that both requires signup?

Tags: api, oauth, automation, single-sign-on

Am teacher and I make and sell Question bank (qbnak) for many standardize test.

I've built a business using two different service, in which both requires sign-up, So If i had a customer he should create two account one for the first service and another for the second in order to get to qbank **each time**

The first service is [Teachable](http://www.Teachable.com) and the second is [Speedexam](http://www.Speedexam.net) .

**So my Questions is:**

How to automate user signup rather than doing it manually?

What is the permanent solution for this, What do you call it SSO/oAuth or API ?

And what are my options if SSO and API are not support in both services?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you mentioned, what you're trying to achieve is generally referred to as SSO.

> Single Sign On works by having a central server, which all the applications trust. When you login for the first time a cookie gets created on this central server. Then, whenever you try to access a second application, you get redirected to the central server, if you already have a cookie there, you will get redirected directly to the app with a token, without login prompts, which means you’re already logged in.

(source: [How to Implement Single Sign On](https://auth0.com/learn/how-to-implement-single-sign-on/))

You have a few options on how to implement this:

- Create your own authentication server and define your own processes around how the other application interact and perform authentication

  ⤷ *(**not recommend**, time consuming and easy to get something wrong)*
- Create your own authentication server compliant with available authentication standards like OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0

  ⤷ *(time consuming and complex, but at least you're following standards so less likely to really mess up)*
- Delegate the authentication to a third-party authentication provider like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/)

  ⤷ *(easy to get started, depending on amount of usage it will cost you money instead of time)*

---

**Disclosure**: Answer provider by an Auth0 employee.

Comment: Thank you João Angelo, one more Question, Can I do this even if both site don't offers SSO service?

Comment: Yes, even if the two sites are not interested in allowing SSO among themselves you can use the authentication server in such way that users only have to signup once there and then can login to the other two sites with the same credentials.